# htaccess mod_rewrite about?subpage=mission

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I am trying to use `mod_rewrite` to clean up the `$_GET[]` info from the URL

Currently have this as my .htaccess

```
# BEGIN Rewrite

ErrorDocument 404 /404.php

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

# END Rewrite
```

I have and about.php page that has a few sub pages and with that .htaccess file it looks like

```
http://domain.com/about
```

to view the subpage "mission" It would look like

```
http://domain.com/about?subpage=mission
```

What is the best way to clean this URL up? I suck at the .htaccess stuff.

Comment: clean url how? what do you desire? show an example or two

Comment: Something along the lines of http://domain.com/about/mission

Answer (score 1):

### EDIT

Edited to show a generic rule:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /([^?]+)\?subpage=([^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^.+$ /%1/%2? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^(.+)/([^/]+)/?$ /$1.php?subpage=$2 [L]
```

Comment: Now is there a way to do this for any page I create?

Comment: @NicholasPanella It'd depend on what the query parameters would be for those pages, if the parameter is same (`subpage`), then you can replace `/about\?` with `(?:about|some|other|page/with|paths)\?`

Comment: I got this
`RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ (?:about|members)\?subpage=([^&\s]+) [NC]`
How about this part then (below)??
`RewriteRule ^about/?$ /about/%1? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^about/(.+)/?$ /about.php?subpage=$1 [L]`

Comment: I suppose there wouldn't be a way to use a * to just get the name of any php file and apply the same rule where it replaces ?subpage=somename

Comment: @NicholasPanella Edited the answer above to show a generic rule.